# 'Earth' or 'earth' in Christian/theological texts

Tags: word-usage

I am writing a book about the Gospel of Thomas and am using the word 'earth' 116 times

> (Jesus walked on E/earth...;
>   If the understanding that the E/earth is not at the center of the universe was revolutionary...;
>   The E/earth and everything on it consists of atoms...)

I don't know if E/earth, since it refers to planet E/earth, should be capitalized or lowercase. Google says, if you use an article ('the earth'), it should be lowercase while ('on Earth') should be uppercase. Is that a fixed rule? Since always the planet E/earth is spoken of, would the reader be confused that sometimes 'Earth' is capitalized and sometimes not?

I am quoting a lot of Bible verses and Bible texts usually use lowercase for 'earth', so than one would get 'on earth' - lowercase when a Bible verse is quoted, but 'on Earth' - capitalized within the text, which I find inconsistent.

If anybody could recommend how I might handle this issue, I would greatly appreciate it.

I have googled extensively but still can't find the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. Andrew's answer is very thoughtful and points to what Lambie said. Who knows what the ancients thought, I just googled and already since the 3rd century BC the spherical shape of the earth was established. Fact is, ancient Greek texts used lowercase throughout and 'earth' in all its variations (with article or without) is mostly translated into English as lowercase. So, when I comment on these passages, in my commentary or text, would I simply maintain the lowercase in disregard of what geekahedron researched (and is all over google, Earth as planet)? Like 'thy will be

Comment: The main point I was making is that one should only make use of Biblical translation sources and the scholars who have done this work and not worry about English usage sources re using capital letters. And,furthermore, it would be useful to consult a scholar about the original language, which, seems to have been written in Syriac. Wikipedia says: Scholars have proposed a date as early as 40 AD or as late as 140 AD

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you sometimes see "earth" and sometimes "Earth" should tell you that there probably is no *rule*, at least with regard to the Bible.  Depending on the source, all of the texts you read were originally translated from Ancient Greek or Aramaic, and probably mirror the translator's interpretation of which best fits the word in the original language.

Therefore the only way to answer your question is to talk about what might make more sense to the *modern* reader ... but again, this is really a matter of opinion.  When ancient texts say something like "he walked the earth" (lowercase), they don't mean:

> He walked the entire surface area of a roughly spherical planet, third from the Sun

As you know, people of that day didn't think of the actual Earth as a planetary body.  Instead they simply thought of it as a very large place that was everything which existed outside of the literal heavens (sun, moon, planets, and stars) and the figurative *other* places of the afterlife.  Instead they mean something more like:

> He walked the **land**

meaning

> He walked an **unspecified distance**, going *from place to place*

or even figuratively

> He walked **everywhere** (it was possible for man in that day to walk)

Uppercase "Earth" generally refers to the portion of the universe created by God where humans *live*, which is to say:

> This **mortal realm**

or

> This **plane of existence**

You can tell the lines between these two concepts are blurry, which is why I say it's a matter of personal opinion.  One person might draw a clear distinction between the "earth" as in "the physical limits of the places humans can travel", and the "Earth" as in "the place in which we exist before death" ... but in an era of science fiction and space travel, is there really a difference?

That being said, you would certainly write something like

> God is King of the **Earth**

and not "earth", because in Christian belief the supreme deity is the ruler of *everything*, both literal and figurative.  With mere humans, even prophets, it would be your choice which to use, depending on what exactly you wish to imply.

Answer (score 0):

The AP suggests "generally lowercase" and in your case I would probably use lowercase everywhere, since you are not speaking in a celestial or astronomical context
([RuthlessEditor](https://ruthlesseditor.com/when-to-capitalize-earth/)).

When used to refer to the planet (as a celestial body) and not preceded by an article, "Earth" should always be capitalized (as a proper noun).

When used to refer to dirt, land, or soil, "earth" should never be capitalized.

When referring to the planet, but preceded by an article, capitalization of "the earth" or "the Earth" is inconsistent and largely a matter of style. Most often, though, "the earth" is not capitalized, and "Earth" as a proper noun does not take an article ([MLA](https://style.mla.org/capitalizing-earth-sun-moon/)).

[Grammarist](https://grammarist.com/style/earth/) says "the earth" should not be capitalized, but previously said that it should be when referring to the planet. Interestingly, the same search result shows both (reflecting a change in opinion on the matter):
[image]

Also of note, idiomatic expressions follow their own rules and are generally uncapitalized, such as "where on earth," "down to earth," or "move heaven and earth." ([dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/e/earth/)).
Saying "walked on earth" is idiomatic and also more frequently uncapitalized, as seen in this [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=walked+on+earth%2Cwalked+on+Earth&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15).

Finally, the Bible has its own set of style rules, which is not always the same from on translation to another (for example, when speaking about God, whether or not to capitalize His pronouns). When you are directly quoting a specific text or translation, it's generally understood that you are copying it exactly as you found it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to consult existing versions of the Bible in English, rather than English-learning etc. site:

[versions of the Bible in English](https://www.biblestudytools.com/bible-versions/)

for example: in the Standard English version, you get:

1 In the beginning, God created the heavens and the earth.

I did not go through every version, but I am pretty sure it would be earth.

The Gospel of Thomas only was found in 1945. It is not part of the traditional Christian Bibles but it is very interesting.

Here are two scholars who translated it and they use lower-case:

12. The disciples said to Jesus, "We know that you are going to leave us. Who will be our leader?"

Jesus said to them, "No matter where you are you are to go to James the Just, for whose sake heaven and earth came into being."

There are five other versions of The Gospel of Thomas, and all use lower-case.

I doubt highly that the word earth was understood as a planet at the time these documents were written. That explains why the translations use lower case.

In the expression heaven and earth, earth was the flat place inhabited by humans.

[Nag Hammadi Scriptures](http://gnosis.org/naghamm/gosthom.html)